# Why amazon cognito authorizer works just as authenticator not as an authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Why amazon **cognito authorizer** is not working as an authorizer even it can get the role from the authentication token and the role has assigned allow and deny policy. It just works as an authenticator not as authorizer.

Comment: Because IT IS an authenticator. Naming it as authorizer is just unfortunate by AWS.

Comment: ok, so should we go for IAM authorizer.

Comment: You could. You can also roll out your own custom authorizer

Comment: Thanks @KhalidT.

Comment: hi @KhalidT. I tried aws_iam authorizer. Now authorization is working correctly but i am not able to pass the user details throws integration mapping to my lamda function.
I am using 
**"tenantId": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub"**

Comment: I suggest that you post this as a new question :)